# $(\kappa \times 2,<_{lex}) \cong (\kappa,\in )$ for cardinal numbes $\kappa$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

A cardinal number $\alpha$ is a ordinal number such that $\forall \beta < \alpha : \beta \not\approx \alpha$.
Now I want to show that for a cardinal number $\kappa$ the set $\kappa \times 2$ with the lexicographic order $<_{lex}$ defined by $(a,b) <_{lex} (a',b') :\iff a < a' \lor (a' = a \land b < b')$ is order isomorph to $\kappa$ with the well order $\in$.

So far I was able to show that $\forall \lambda < \kappa : \kappa \times 2 \approx \lambda$ and for infinite ordinal numbers $\alpha$ one has $\kappa \times 2 \approx \alpha$.

Edit: By transfinite induction on $\kappa$. We know $\omega \times 2 \approx \omega$ and $|\omega \times 2| = \omega$. Thus we can assume that it holds for smaller infinite cardinals $\lambda < \kappa$ und prove it for $\kappa$.
My Idea is to note that $<_{lex}$ is a well ordering on $\kappa \times 2$ and starts out by
\begin{equation}
(0,0) <_{lex} (1,0) <_{lex} (2,0) <_{lex} (3,0)  <_{lex} \ldots <_{lex} (\omega,0) <_{lex} (\omega,1).
\end{equation}
Now each $(a,b) \in \kappa \times 2$ has $|\max(a,b) + 1 \times \max(a,b) + 1| < \kappa$ many $<_{lex}$ predecessors and $otp((\kappa \times 2)) = \kappa$ hence there must be a order isomorphism between $(\kappa \times 2, <_{lex})$ and $(\kappa, \in)$.

Comment: What makes you think this is true at all?

Comment: At least it is true for $\omega_0$ since one can construct a chain $\lbrace (1,0),(1,1),(2,0), (2,1), \ldots \rbrace$ in increasing order which is order isomorphic to $\omega_0$. Therefore $2 \times \omega_0$ is order isomorphic to $\omega_0$ and more general $n \times \omega_0$ is order isomorphic to $\omega_0$. So my thought to show this was to use a similar approach but I am not sure how.

Comment: I think you mean to be considering $\kappa\times 2$ rather than $2\times\kappa$.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking: $\kappa$ has to be infinite or $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show is that if $\kappa$ is a cardinal then it is the unique order type of a well-order that has *cardinality* $\kappa$ and every proper initial segment has size $<\kappa$.

So, for example, $\omega$ is the unique well-ordering that is countable and has every proper initial segment finite. And $\omega_1$ is the unique order type of a well-order which is uncountable and every proper initial segment is countable.

So, to prove that $\kappa\times2$ is isomorphic to $\kappa$, it is enough to show that any proper initial segment has size $<\kappa$, as very easily $\kappa\times2$ has cardinality $\kappa$.

For this, show that if $A\subseteq\kappa\times2$ is a proper initial segment, then there is some $\gamma<\kappa$ such that $A\subseteq\gamma\times2$.